# custom-made UserControl property binding in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I've a custom-made user control:

```
public class CustomUC : UserControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    private string PropertyX { get { ... } ; set { ... }; }
}
```

I'm using it from another form. On this form I'm using a DataSource.

The problem is that I'm unable to figure out how to bind this `PropertyX` to some field of my DataSource.

**EDIT**

My `DataSource` is a `System.Windows.Forms.BindSource` object I've created on design-time. I've set a class to this `datasource` in order to be linked to a `ClassA`. This class has a property `Notes` I'd like to bind to `CustomMadeUCPropertyX`...

Comment: You can use either designer or code. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you specify which `DataSource` you mean? Of a control like a `button`? What do you want to do with this property?

Comment: @rbr94, I'just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should try following way to bind property by coding:

```
object.DataBindings.Add("PropertyX", YourDataSrouce, "columnname in your datasource")
```